# What is the difference between em and en in CSS

Tags: css, font-size

I am working with some (problematic and strange) css, and I am wondering what the difference between en and em is when determining sizes `font-size:12en; height:3em;`.

Comment: Where do you see `en` as a unit besides this code? It doesn't exist.

Comment: I see, the [em](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/em/info) tag wiki page is misleading... It's because the tag wiki is not *only* about the CSS unit `em`.

Comment: DOES exist! but not for web! see my answer

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Not in CSS it doesn't.

Comment: Madmartigan that's a good point althougb the wiki page does have a section in it about em, but no link to a page that is em specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is not likely to be useful to future readers since there is no such thing as an `en` unit in CSS, so it is not possible to make this comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid in HTML/CSS however it is used in non-web print presses:
Wikipedia mentions it under [em](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29):

> The width of the em space ( ) is defined to be 1 em, as is the em dash (—).
>   By contrast, the narrower unit **en** is half an em.

Comment: You're thinking of typography, this is a CSS question.

Comment: I'm not really thinking of anything I'm just answering the question about en and showing that although invalid it might have come from the user thinking about the non-online world.  Just adding some extra info that some folks enjoy beyond "it's invalid and a typo"

Comment: `font-size:12en;` is an invalid typo. `en` has no meaning (currently) in CSS. The question title is "What is the difference between em and en in CSS". **CSS** `<--`

Comment: I think we've kinda exhausted the topic right for meaningful comment?  And we can also disagree whether the extra info's helpful and let other folks vote right?  Good hanging wid ya.

Comment: Yeah it's fine, you just kept urging me to read your answer as if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS 'em' is a relative typographical unit that is equal to the font-size. If your font-size is 12px, then 1em is 12px for that element. Since 'em' is a relative unit of measurement, this helps when making typographical changes to multiple elements with different font sizes, for instance if you have:

```
<style> 
h1{ font-size: 24px; }
p{ font-size: 15px; }
.spacedout{ letter-spacing:1em; }
</style>

<h1 class="spacedout">Heading</h1>
<p class="spacedout">Paragraph</p>
```

then the spacing between letters would be visually equal.